# round shape in button is not properly displaying

Tags: android

for background of first button i have used shape which is below

1)  left_round_shape_button.xml

```
<solid android:color="#0084ff" />

<corners
    android:radius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

for setting background of second button i have used below code

2) right_round_shape_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color -->
<solid android:color="#0084ff" />

<corners
    android:radius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Now when i set this into buttons

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSticker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/left_round_shape_button"
        android:text="Sticker"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMySticker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/right_round_shape_button"
        android:text="My Sticker" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but these are not looking proper :(

[image]

why first button is coming with all round shape and why second is not coming :(

from android docs i have read following

```
Note: Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no 
corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use 
android:radius to set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and every
corner with the values you really want, providing zero ("0dp") where you don't want rounded corners.
```

Comment: Try `android:radius="1dp"` (leave 10dp and 0dp for the specific corners) for both

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution, it's problem with XML rendering, when u run your app, you will get proper output,